# Expand/Collapse all list elements in jQuery ui mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to place a button on a webpage that uses jquery ui mobile to structure collapsible lists to expand/collapse all lists. However, I'm fairly new to jquery and javascript coding so I've run into a few problems. I've placed the button in but the code for it is not responding upon clicking it. How would I go about correcting this code so it successfully expands/collapses?

The code for the button is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js">

$('#collapsible1').click("click", showHide);

var collapsible = $('.collapsible');
collapsible.hide();

function showHide() {
    if(collapsible.is(':hidden'))
        collapsible.slideDown();
    else
        collapsible.slideUp();
}

</script>
```

The button is initialized as such:

```
<button id="collapsible1">Show/Hide</button>
```

The template I'm testing it in is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TLittler/9ndzm3cc/5/

Comment: `collapsible..is` `..` (double dot)??

Comment: I didn't catch that error. That's embarrassing.

Comment: Are you wanting to expand/collapse the entire tree when you click on the button?

Comment: @Stef Yes. For some strange reason it hides the list headers to start.

Comment: I found that removing the .hide( ) attribute on collapsible fixed that but using toggle seems to just hide both list headers regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collapsible widget has expand and collapse methods:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#method-expand

So you can expand all collapsibles like this:

```
$('[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible( "expand" );
```

and collapse them like this:

```
$('[data-role="collapsible"]').collapsible( "collapse" );
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/9ndzm3cc/11/)**

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it. This is the correct answer. I prepared a fiddle that works with OP's original design if they're interested: http://jsfiddle.net/9ndzm3cc/12/

Comment: @Stef, thanks for sharing your solution! Yours is correct if OP wants to toggle the state of each collapsible. Mine, as is, will simply collapse all or expand all regardless of current state of any collapsible.

Comment: Right you are! Thanks for pointing that out. The following fiddle fixes that: http://jsfiddle.net/9ndzm3cc/13/